# Modifying $PATH variable by a bash alias

Tags: bash, path, alias

I created this alias in my `.bashrc` file:

```
alias changepath="export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

What I want to do is change `$JAVA_HOME` and then change the `$PATH` to include the new `$JAVA_HOME/bin`.

When I change `$JAVA_HOME` and type this command instead of using the alias, it works as expected.
However, when I change `$JAVA_HOME` and then use the alias, the `changepath` command prepends the old `$JAVA_HOME/bin` instead of the new `$JAVA_HOME/bin` to `$PATH`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use a function instead:

```
changepath () {
    export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH";
}
```

In your case `"$JAVA_HOME` and `$PATH` are interpreted when you set the alias. So they are fixed to the moment when you execute the `.bashrc`.

With a function, variables will be interpreted at launching.

> **Note:** I copy/paste you `export PATH=...`, but be careful you will add `$PATH`'s content at every launch.

Comment: Zulu: `...be careful you will add $PATH ...` Ha! great minds thing alike! ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You can also defer evaluation of variables by single-quoting  your alias definition, i.e.

```
alias changepath='export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH'
```

Note that the alias or function solutions do not solve the problem of clearing any previous JAVA_HOME you have set.

So you can wind up with a crazy PATH

```
 PATH="/usr/bin:/sys"

 PATH=/usr/bin/java:/usr/bin:/sys

 PATH=/usr/bin/java/bin:/usr/bin/java:/usr/bin:/sys
```

Comment: Does absolutely nothing on my system (MacOS Catalina)...  :-(

Comment: @PatrickT : I just re-tested this (a original is long time ago now ;-) ) and in my MSYS2 bash 4.4.12 version, it works. (and I'm pretty sure it worked when I posted it). You did then execute the alias `changepath` after you created the alias with code above? If your `JAVA_HOME` var was empty, you should sttill see a leading `:` . Not sure how else to help. Hopefully the accepted answer above, using a `function` does work? Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'm using the zsh terminal, perhaps that makes a difference? I also tried all combinations of single and double quotes, e.g. `alias changepath='export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"'` or `alias changepath="export PATH='$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH'"` or without any quotes... Strange...  Yes the solution based on a function worked, so not to worry.  :-)

Comment: @PatrickT : Glad you found a solution. I don't see how using `zsh` could possible affect this, as the cmds we're talking about are super-basic features of all *nix based shells. Just double check your code for typos of `JAVA_HOME` and if all is good, then be happy the function solution works! Good luck.

Comment: I have no idea. I'm sure you're right. I merely copy-pasted your code. The function solution is your code wrapped in a function, and that works, so I don't know...

Comment: single quoting did the trick - evaluates the variables on use (macOS Catalina, both bash / zsh). we saved the pre-image of the PATH as PATH_000 which can then be used to create a modified PATH after changing JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 2):

This is how I approached the problem of changing between Java 7 and 8 SDKs. I am sure someone could improve these bash functions but I guess the important part is using *sed* to edit the path.

This will find and replace the JAVA_HOME value rather than keep adding to the PATH variable.

```
function java7 () {
  export PATH=$(echo $PATH | sed s~$JAVA_HOME~${JAVA_7_HOME}"/bin"~)
  export JAVA_HOME="${JAVA_7_HOME}";
}

function java8 () {
  export PATH=$(echo $PATH | sed s~$JAVA_HOME~${JAVA_8_HOME}"/bin"~)
  export JAVA_HOME="${JAVA_8_HOME}";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I need to switch between 8 and 11 so what I did was:

1. Add NO_JAVA_PATH in .profile

```
    export NO_JAVA_PATH=$PATH
    export JAVA_HOME="<path>"
    export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

2. Added aliases in .bashrc

```
    alias j8='export JAVA_HOME="<path>" ; export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$NO_JAVA_PATH'
    alias j11='export JAVA_HOME="<path>" ; export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$NO_JAVA_PATH'
```